# Gigabit ethernet port on RPi Zero W or 2W

Tags: pi-zero-w

Is there any good adapter that can plug into either my RPi Zero W or RPi Zero 2 W's micro USB port and provide an Ethernet port that negotiates as a Gigabit port? *I don't actually need Gigabit capacity, just for the adapter to say that it is. I guess, a way to modify a common microUSB to 100Mbit Ethernet adapter to say it's 1Gbit works too. The actual bandwidth capacity is completely irrelevant to my project.*

**I'm fully aware that this connection will never *actually* transfer at a gigabit speed, and the RPi's microUSB port maxes out at ~450 mbit. I'm connecting it to a commercial LED driver board called a Colorlight, which requires hosts be connected with a "Gigabit ethernet" port, but only actually uses 1 Mbit or less. I know the usual answers would be to use another board, or a HAT, or something else, to get closer to actual gig performance, but we need this to fit in a very tight space, I assume the above fake adapter would be smaller and simpler, and a true gig port would be additional space/cost/power for no benefit.**

Comment: put an ethernet network switch on the back of Colorlight display ... it looks like there is lots of room

Comment: I was looking for a specific model number since I bought a few that didn't work... Trendnet TU3-ETG works :)

Comment: `looking for a specific model number` is a shopping question ... that is off topic here